# Hover issue for Menu Item with padding

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, menu, hover

Here is a sample code I'm working on:

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"  CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .menu
        {
            border: 1px solid #C0C0C0;
            color: #FFFFFF;
            background-color: #66A6CC;
            font-family: Cambria;
            text-align: justify;
            font-size: medium;
            width: 200px;
            padding:8px;
            padding-left:0px;
            text-indent:10px;
            display:inline-table;
        }
        .menu:hover
        {
            background-color: #FFFFA6;
            color: #000000;
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div style="float:left; margin:10px;">
        <asp:Menu ID="Menu1" runat="server" StaticMenuItemStyle-CssClass="menu" >
            <Items>
                <asp:MenuItem Text="Menu row" Value="menurow"  
                    NavigateUrl="Default2.aspx" ></asp:MenuItem>
                <asp:MenuItem Text="Menu row" Value="menurow1" 
                    NavigateUrl="Default2.aspx" ></asp:MenuItem>
                <asp:MenuItem Text="Menu row" Value="menurow2" 
                    NavigateUrl="Default2.aspx" ></asp:MenuItem>
            </Items>
        </asp:Menu>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I have a problem with hover. [Here it is.](http://g1204.hizliresim.com/w/1/4014c.png)

The whole cell should turn into yellow but it doesn't do because of padding.

EDIT: I removed padding but same thing happens again. I think it's because of display type. I tried most of display types but they are not convenient for a menu.

**Solution:** There is a problem with Chrome about rendering some components. There are online solutions, please Google "ASP.NET chrome menu problem".

Comment: No, it doesn't. Pass your mouse over a menu item, stay close to borders. A rectangle around the item turns to yellow, not entire item. I want entire item to turn to yellow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working from copying your HTML code. The only thing I changed was adding a missing closing bracket to the ".menu:hover" class.

I tested the page in Firefox and Internet Explorer 8.

Padding shouldn't be causing any issues with the yellow hover. What browser are you using?

Answer (score 1):

this your code output in my chrome with padding 18px :

[image]

Comment: When I pass over the cursor in the middle of menu item, I get same result. When cursor is close to borders, a yellow rectangle appears and it's blue inside it. I removed padding, same thing happens but a thinner rectangle.